# Execute a function with sliding delay

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I have an html page which diplays a list of some elements. There is a textbox which allows the user to filter the elements. To update the displayed elements, I need to do an ajax call to retrieve the elements that match the filter value. I want the ajax call to be executed two seconds after the last letter was typed in the filter textbox. I know about `settimeout` but I want the two second delay to be "sliding", meaning that if within the two second delay period the user types another letter, then I want to reset the delay. How would I go about that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setTimeout` returns a handle (a number) that you can use to cancel the timer via `clearTimeout`, so your handler for the keydown event can do this:

```
var timerHandle = 0;
function handler() {
    // Clear the previous timer if it hasn't already happened
    if (timerHandle != 0) {
        clearTimeout(timerHandle);
    }

    // Call `tick` in 2 seconds or so
    timerHandle = setTimeout(tick, 2000);
}
function tick() {
    // The timer has gone off, clear the handle
    timerHandle = 0;
}
```

Note that we're clearing `timerHandle` when the timer function is run; otherwise, the next keydown will cause us to try to cancel a timer that doesn't exist anymore. I've never met a browser that complained, but then, I've never pushed my luck, either...